# Android Popup window with listview doesn't fit screen height with WRAP_CONTENT , Why?

Tags: android, listview, popup, height

I an trying to display a PopWindow(whose height is to WRAP_CONTENT),which has a ListView inside it.If the content of list is more then popup window is not displayed at the exact position.

created Popup window:

```
mPopUp = new PopupWindow(mLayOut,popUpWidth ,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
```

show at Location:

```
mPopUp.showAtLocation(mLayOut, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, xPos, yPos);
```

I have attached the screenshots

i)When Button One is clicked it works fine
[image: When Button One is clicked]

ii) **when button two is selected,Y position got changed to the top of the screen**
[image: when button two is selected]

Comment: give your list a static height in `dip`

Comment: if static height is specified,less number elements is list will have empty spaces.But i don't want those empty space to be shown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487552/limit-height-of-listview-on-android define `weight` for the element enclosing listview

Comment: Only thing i was able to achieve was to change the height of the List view when it exceeds the screen size by overriding onMeasure(). Let me know is there any other solution.