# android listview displays in very large height

Tags: android, listview, textview, height

i am creating custom listview containning textview only..
( i will not like Setting height of the root LinearLayout of custom_textview.xml mean fixing the height)

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="2dip"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/my_list_selector" >
    </ListView>

    <!-- <ListView -->
    <!-- android:id="@+id/lv_diseases" -->
    <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_height="match_parent" -->
    <!-- android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" -->
    <!-- android:layout_marginTop="5dp" -->
    <!-- android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" > -->


    <!-- </ListView> -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Empty List"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is getview method in listview_Adpter
@

```
Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_textview, null);

            view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_content);

            view.txtViewTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            view.txtViewTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(parent
                    .getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/DroidSerif.ttf"));

            convertView.setTag(view);

        }

        else {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        System.gc();
        try {
            view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("this is error " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

and this is custom_textview.xml inside my textview is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Definig a container for you List Item-->
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Defining where should text be placed. You set you text color here-->
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="sample"
         android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="7dp"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is how i implement

```
 listview_Adpter la = new listview_Adpter(getActivity(), listname);
            lv.setAdapter(la);
```

every thing works fine but list view display data in very big height how to overcome it? i want to show it in middle

Comment: Setting height of the root `LinearLayout` of `custom_textview.xml` file will do the trick.

Comment: check this for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216489/how-to-reduce-listview-item-height

Comment: Your text view in listitem is of big height or the height of the list item ?

Comment: no space remain mean text contain not large

Comment: may be your content having space.. then try this  view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position).trim());

Comment: yesss... this worked... add as ans so i can accept as answer... thanks a lot was doning a silly mistake

Answer (score 2):

**android:layout_marginTop="232dp"** ?? Do you really need that ... i think this is what is causing the height problem.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild your project after removing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the of the custom_textview android:layout_height from "fill_parent" to "match_parent"

Comment: Sorry, I meant to change to wrap_content

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the LinearLayout in custom_textview.xml
It's not needed at all.

You might need to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to your TextView, as well as changing its gravity to `android:gravity="left | center_vertical"`

**[EDIT]**

Your final row item layout (custom_textview.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Defining a List Item-->
<!-- Defining where should text be placed. You set you text color here-->
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_content"
    android:textColor="#f000"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="sample"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="7dp"
/>
```

**[EDIT 2]**

Some more ideas for customizing your row:

You can even go further specific and give the item a decoration (a 9 patch to add a border or a background color which could also be different for even and odd items).
You can also add custom margins and/or paddings to the row.
And you could even add an embedded (compound) drawable to it.
The text can have an inset or raised aspect (play with the text color and its shadow).

All this with a single TextView!!

Comment: See my edited answer. By the way, you don't need to set the text, since you're going to change it in code. Also note that I fixed the **deprecated** (since API Level 8) "fill_parent" with its equivalent "match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

Use the below layout as `custom_textview.xml`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="sample"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your `ListView` item's height is looking bigger because, your are applying `17dp padding` and `4dp margin` at the top and `7dp padding` and `4dp margin` at the bottom of the `Textview`...so, its taking  total `32dp` extra space excluding your `TextView`. Minimize them as the above layout...I think, your problem will be solved.