# Populating Listview causes the other element to partially hide

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am new to android layout and having the following problem in my app:

here's the layout for fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_books_to_issue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.87"

    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_empylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.87"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_flask"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<View
    style="@style/Divider"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_newbook_upcoming_issues"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="New"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.13"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

I turn the ImageView's(`imageView_empylist`) visibility on when the ListView(`listview_books_to_issue`) is empty, so far the button `add_newbook_upcoming_issues` looks good, but when the listview is populated even with a single item the button gets hidden partially in the bottom.

Here's the layout code for the item used to populate list.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_upcoming_issues_book_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_upcoming_issues_book_author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="By:-Author"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_to_issue_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="to be issued on"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_upcoming_issues_book_no"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Don't know what's causing it, any help?
Thanks in advance :)

PS: I am using weights instead of height so that I can have a fixed ratio of screen for items. If in case this is causing the problem please mention the correct way of doing this.

**EDIT** found the solution here [Limit height of ListView on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487552/limit-height-of-listview-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main layout fragment, please use `RealativeLayout` replace for `LinearLayout`. Your ListView will be `layout_above` for these views

Comment: any particular reason why it doesn't works with Linear Layout?

Comment: The 'layout_weight' won't correct when the height or width is over the ratio that you set.