# Android ScrollView set height for displayed content

Tags: android, xml, layout, scrollview, xamarin

I'm having a lot of trouble trying solve the issue of having a static height scrollable area within a layout. I have three long lists that need to be displayed on the same screen and it would be entirely impractical to display all of the entries sequentially because then if you want to skip a category you need to scroll past possibly hundreds of entries.

Assume I have a scroll view with a Linear Layout inside of it, I want this to take up say, 250dp height on the screen at max and be independently scrollable once populated with more entries than can fit in 250dp's space.

What I have now is:

```
<ScrollView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="150px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/XXXXXXX"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/XXXXXX" />
</ScrollView>
```

When populated, the scrollview and linearlayout just stretch as long as they needs to to fit the content and displays all of it *instead* of having a "window" of 250dp/px (any measurment would be nice) with the content scrollable within it.

I'm new to the android platform, so perhaps the answer is obvious and I just didn't understand the language, but any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

--- SOLVED:
Put a linearLayout outside of the ScrollView with the height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a `maxHeight`. But since views do not support it, you have to use a workaround.

Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811461/770467

Comment: I got the sizing part to work with your article, but now that area isn't scrolling. I've updated the question with the new code. Thank you so far!

Comment: That's strange, I've just run a sample and it scrolls fine, here's the layout: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=R45Z7wBi

Comment: @ExceptionAl the pasteBin website says "This paste has been removed!"

Answer (score 22):

With some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23617530/2642390) answer I managed to wrap up a very basic ScrollView component you can use for this case:

Create a custom class extending a ScrollView and do the following modifications:

```
public class MaxHeightScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private int maxHeight;

    public MaxHeightScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MaxHeightScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MaxHeightScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MaxHeightScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MaxHeightScrollView);
            maxHeight = styledAttrs.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.MaxHeightScrollView_maxHeight, 200); //200 is a default value
            styledAttrs.recycle();
        }
    }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
       heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
       super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
   }
}
```

And then one minor thing left is to declare your styleable in the attrs.xml file of your values folder(If you don't have one, just create an xml file with this name in the values folder of your project's res folder). Add the following lines there:

```
<declare-styleable name="MaxHeightScrollView">
    <attr name="maxHeight" format="dimension" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And use your new ScrollView as follows:

```
<com.yourpackage.MaxHeightScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:maxHeight="300dp">
</com.yourpackage.MaxHeightScrollView>
```

Credits go to [whizzle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1687169/whizzle) for quickly wrapping this up!

Comment: It works except that I dont know how to use the attribute in my xml.

Answer (score 4):

My simple solution.
Set `ScrollView` heigh in xml:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Add this code to set Max Height to 200 if current measured Height is > 200

```
sv.measure(0, 0);
if (nsv.getMeasuredHeight() > 200) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
        sv.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

---

`ScrollView` in my example is into `LinearLayout`, so I used `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Add a layout around your ScrollView with fixed height