# How to set a maximum height with wrap content in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, height

In android, how can you create a scroll view that's got a max height, and wrap contents, basically it wraps the content vertically, but has a maximum height?

I tried

```
<ScrollView 
     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:maxHeight="200dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/maincontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But this isn't working?

Comment: here is another solution to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694355/how-to-set-recyclerview-max-height/48970129#48970129

Answer (score 36):

you can add this to any view (override onMeasure in a class inherited from a view)

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (maxHeight > 0){
        int hSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int hMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

        switch (hMode){
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Math.min(hSize, maxHeight), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                break;
            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                break;
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Math.min(hSize, maxHeight), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                break;
        }
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: how to use this?

Comment: @c-an extend some view class, override onMeasure method of the class.

Answer (score 22):

I've extended ScrollView and added code to implement this feature:

https://gist.github.com/JMPergar/439aaa3249fa184c7c0c

I hope that be useful.

Comment: This implementation works at once. The only thing I would add is the maxHeight parameter in a/the res/values/attrs.xml file to be able to specify it right in the XML (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr)

Answer (score 20):

You can do it programmatically.

```
 private static class OnViewGlobalLayoutListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    private final static int maxHeight = 130;
    private View view;

    public OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (view.getHeight() > maxHeight)
            view.getLayoutParams().height = maxHeight;
    }
}
```

And add listener to the view:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver()
                  .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(view));
```

Listener will call method onGlobalLayout(), when view height will be changed.

Comment: I think that you need to remove the `void` on your `OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(View view)` constructor.

Comment: I like this solution because it avoids the need for a custom View class, and can therefore be applied to any View type. By the way, it didn't work for me at first - I had to modify the way you set the height to use `setLayoutParams` after modifying the `LayoutParams` retrieved from `getLayoutParams` (as described at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2963152/995218).

Answer (score 7):

It can be done by wrapping the view into [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) and using `layout_constraintHeight_max` attribute.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">

        ...

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the example above, the parent `ConstraintLayout` height is limited to `200dp`, and the child `ScrollView` height wraps the content till it's less than `200dp`. Note that `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"` aligns the child `ScrollView` at the top of the parent, otherwise it will be centered.

Comment: This works for my requirement thanks @Valeriy katkov

Answer (score 0):

for set scrollview height you must use 2 linerlayout inside together and then set scrool view as them child then set middle linerlayout layout:height for limit scrollview height.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a class to handle setting maximum height to what is passed by the user:

```
public class OnViewGlobalLayoutListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {


private Context context;
private int maxHeight;
private View view;

public OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(View view, int maxHeight, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.view = view;
    this.maxHeight = dpToPx(maxHeight);
}

@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if (view.getHeight() > maxHeight) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = maxHeight;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}

public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}

public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return px;
}
}
```

2.) Attach this to the view and pass the maximum height in DP:

```
messageBody.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
             new OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(messageBody, 256, context)
             );
```

Thanks to @harmashalex for the inspiration. I made modifications to as setting the layout params didn't work by @harma's code. Also, dp-to-px conversion is necessary to offload wondering about it.

Answer (score -7):

Here you can set height of your Scrollview like this -:

```
<ScrollView 
 android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

           <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/maincontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

           </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Certainly doesn't answer the question!