# DialogFragment shown as Dialog resizes to full screen on orientation change

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm implementing a dialog with two `EditText` fields. According to the Material Design specs, this kind of dialog should be shown fullscreen on smaller devices whereas on large screens it should be shown in a dialog window.

To achieve this, I've followed the implementation from the developer.android.com [guide  on Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog).

This works fine for smaller screens but for large screens the dialog window occupies the full screen after an orientation change.

Code for showing the `DialogFragment` (part of `onOptionsItemSelected()` in my `AppCompatActivity`)

```
mIsLargeLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.large_layout);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
mDialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(mIsLargeLayout);

if (mIsLargeLayout)
{
    // The device is using a large layout, so show the fragment as a dialog
    mDialog.show(fragmentManager, "dialog");
}
else
{
    // The device is smaller, so show the fragment fullscreen
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    // To make it fullscreen, use the 'content' root view as the container
    // for the fragment, which is always the root view for the activity
    transaction.add(android.R.id.content, mDialog, "dialog")
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
}
```

For the `DialogFragment`, I override first `onCreateView()` to inflate my custom layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filter_audio_files,
                              container, false);

    // code for Buttons and EditTexts here:
    // set listeners etc.

    return v;
}
```

... and then `onCreateDialog()` with the following statements:

```
Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.c_background_dark);
return dialog;
```

I don't dismiss the `DialogFragment` on orientation change but in `onRestoreInstanceState()` I reconnect to the `DialogFragment` like this:

```
mDialog = (DialogFilterAudiofiles) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
```

While the user is able to complete the dialog no matter what it looks like, I'd like to keep the dialog small - just like it was before the orientation change.

Of course I could dismiss the dialog in `onSaveInstanceState()` after saving the input so far and then show a new dialog in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.
Or I could work with `DialogFragment`s based on `AlertDialog` and `setContentView()` if the screen size is large.

Is there another way to fix the sample code from the guide?

**EDIT**
I'd like to stay as close as possible to the "one layout fits all sizes" approach.

My implementation of "onCreateView()" is inspired by but extending the
sample code, so I've added the relevant part in the text above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem:

> `setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme);`

works fine at first: the `DialogFragment` is created as a full screen dialog or in a small window, depending on the value of `mIsLargeLayout`.

BUT if it has to be recreated after a configuration change, this line causes it to appear fullscreen.

My expectation had been that the value `R.style.AppTheme` would make the runtime look up the custom dialog style which was part of the app theme, but in fact it just treated the `DialogFragment` as a kind of `Activity` when re-creating after a configuration change.

In my case, dropping the whole statement worked as well as using

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, 0);
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setStyle%28int,%20int%29) for the second parameter:

> Optional custom theme. If 0, an appropriate theme (based on the style) will be selected for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the root element of your layout define sizes that don't fill the screen in your dialog layout for your larger devices.  If that doesn't work, see [how-to-set-a-maximum-height-with-wrap-content-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425758/how-to-set-a-maximum-height-with-wrap-content-in-android)

Comment: Will I still have full screen dialogs for small devices with this approach? The sample from the guide suggested it was possible to use one and the same layout for both options. With - OK - some buttons to hide here and a menu to inflate there. The Fragment gets the "mIsLargeLayout" value and adapts to the situation