# How to set the max height for a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I have to `implementing` a `RecylerView`,it should wrap the content if its contain only item content height is less. If the item's increase like `250dp`, it should be set to max `heght(250dp)` and that be able to scroll.How to achieve this.my parent layout is a `Relative layout`.

This is **My Layout file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screen Shot if its only one item.This should be wrap_content.

[image: Screen Shot if its only one item.This should be wrap_content.]

Comment: Use `ScrollView` as the parent layout.

Comment: @AlphaQ `ScrollView` Instead of `RelativeLayout` or current `Relative layout` inside  `ScrollView`

Comment: Why would Google remove maxHeight, it's just a really inconvenient thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

you can programetically set height to `RecylerView`

if only one item... `wrap content`

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=recycler_view.getLayoutParams();
params.height= RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
recycler_view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

else

```
<dimen name="view_height">250dp</dimen>

float height= getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.view_height); //get height

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params_new=recycler_view.getLayoutParams();
params_new.height=height;
recycler_view.setLayoutParams(params_new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178364/1148784

Just create a new class extending RecyclerView and override it's `onMeasure` method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (maxHeight > 0){
            int hSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            int hMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);

            switch (hMode){
                case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Math.min(hSize, maxHeight), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
                    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Math.min(hSize, maxHeight), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                    break;
            }
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

`maxHeight` is in pixels.

You can use this:

```
maxHeight = (int) getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 250;
```

to convert 250 dp into pixels

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a class to handle setting maximum height to what is passed by the user:

```
public class OnViewGlobalLayoutListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {


private Context context;
private int maxHeight;
private View view;

public OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(View view, int maxHeight, Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.view = view;
    this.maxHeight = dpToPx(maxHeight);
}

@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if (view.getHeight() > maxHeight) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = maxHeight;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}

public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}

public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return px;
}
}
```

2.) Attach this to the view and pass the maximum height in DP:

```
messageBody.getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
             new OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(messageBody, 256, context)
             );
```