# How can I set a maximum height for a Scroll View in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-view

**What I want to achieve:**
A java Activity with a belonging xml-layout, where the user can enter the names of all players. Here is how it looks like:

[image: preview]

If you click the plus-button you can enter another player (*Spieler* is german for player). It should be a wrapped view until the maximum height is reached.

I found a very similar question here:
[How to set a maximum height with wrap content in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425758/how-to-set-a-maximum-height-with-wrap-content-in-android)

There is code given with the comment: "you can add this to any view (override onMeasure in a class inherited from a view)"

**Here my question:** My belonging java-file to the xml-layout inherits from Activiy thus doesnt know the super.onMeasure() method. Do you have any tipps what I can do? Can I have an Activity-java-file and a View-java-file to one layout? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a custom view that extends `ScrollView` and then use that view in your xml

```
        public class ScrollViewWithMaxHeight extends ScrollView {

            public static int WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE = -1;

            private int maxHeight = WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE;

            public ScrollViewWithMaxHeight(Context context) {
                super(context);

 init(context, null, 0, 0);
            }

            public ScrollViewWithMaxHeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
 init(context, attrs, 0, 0);
            }

            public ScrollViewWithMaxHeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
                super(context, attrs, defStyle);
 init(context, attrs, defStyle, 0);
            }
           private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes){
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs, R.styleable.custom_ScrollViewWithMaxHeight,  defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
     maxHeight = 
     a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.max_height,maxHeight);
        }

            @Override
            protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
                try {
                    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                    if (maxHeight != WITHOUT_MAX_HEIGHT_VALUE
                            && heightSize > maxHeight) {
                        heightSize = maxHeight;
                    }
                    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(heightSize, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                    getLayoutParams().height = heightSize;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LogManager.error(this, "onMesure", "Error forcing height", e);
                } finally {
                    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                }
            }

            public void setMaxHeight(int maxHeight) {
                this.maxHeight = maxHeight;
            }
        }
```

You also have to create an attrs.xml file in your values folder and add this to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <declare-styleable name="custom_ScrollViewWithMaxHeight">
        <attr name="max_height" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

You can then reference the view like this

```
<the.package.where.the.view.is.ScrollViewWithMaxHeight
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:max_height="150dp">
</the.package.where.the.view.is.ScrollViewWithMaxHeight>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I defined this view. Now I want to declare it in my xml-file. I tried this:
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.ScrollViewWithMaxHeight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            custom:maxHeight="150">

Comment: But where can I define the maxHeight? Do I have to add custom attributes?

Comment: you have to implement the view you've made not the ScrollView. Look at my edited answer

Comment: I have edited my answer again to with the `max_height` attribute

Comment: Here is what I did: 1. Create custom View with your code and 2. changing my <ScrollView.. to <CustomScrollView... as above. I dont get an error but I cant scroll like before :(

Comment: What do you mean you `cant scroll like before`. Have you also added the attrs xml and also look at the view again, I changed it to implement the `max_height`

Comment: Where is the method setMaxHeight() used? I implemented all of this, but it looks exactly like before (with ScrollView) just that I cant scroll (I cannot access the new player when clicking plus)

Comment: You can call it from your xml `app:max_height="yourMaxHeightInDp"` or call it programmatically

Comment: with the new code I get two errors: 1) init(context, 0, 0, 0); --> Error:(19, 23) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to AttributeSet and 2) a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.max_height,maxHeight); --> Error:(35, 52) error: cannot find symbol variable max_height

Comment: For the first problem I've edited the code, check it again :). For the second one have you created and added the `attrs.xml` to your `values` folder?

Comment: yes I did. If I write R.styleable.custom_ScrollViewWithMaxHeight_max_height I dont get any errors, but my app crashes

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that it's supposed to be like `R.styleable.custom_ScrollViewWithMaxHeight_max_height`

Comment: I forgot to write package com.example.. above my class. So now its working, but I have a "fixed" height so the button is not moving downwards, its underneath the maximum height from the beginning

Comment: I guess I can make it work later on, but the scrolling with maximum height works now. So thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Its a so simple.
instead of use `ScrollView`, I prefer you have to use the `RecycleView`, `Adapter` and for plus icon use `Fab` button.

Without creating the custom view and all, you can achieve the maximum hight of `RecycleView` and bottom with `Fab` button by using the`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your `.xml` file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.tejadroid.testing.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="56dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What I want to achieve is that the plus-button is right underneath the last field, if you click "plus", the button goes down, goes down, until its on the bottom and then the scrolling begins. I think its not possible with this suggestion :/

Comment: @NinaSeil, Please refer my edited answer of your question, I think now you can achieve you requirement by using this answer.