# How to edit the height of scroll bar in Android widget "ScrollView"?

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

How can I edit the scroll height in Android "ScrollView"?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by that ?!! editing the Height of scrollView or the height of it's bar ? and what are you did try so far ?

Comment: editing the Height of scrollView or the height of it's bar ? scrollbar

Comment: I want to add custom image for scroll in scrollView

Comment: Make your `ScrollView` width to "fill_parent" .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can't change the `height` of the ScrollView-bar as it depends on the contents of the ScrollView(like any scroll bar), which means you will have a short one for many contents and a tall one for less contents, but instead you can change the width of vertical scrollbars and height of horizontal scrollbars using `android:scrollbarSize=""`, and there is workaround to achieve that, just control the `Height` of the `scrollView` and this will control the Height of it's bar, and to achieve that just refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811461/1638739).

And when talking about adding a custom image for scroll it can be done using:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical=""
```

which

> Defines the vertical scrollbar thumb drawable

or:

```
android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal=""
```

which

> Defines the horizontal scrollbar thumb drawable.

---

**Update:**

To control the width and height of your scroll bar, add your drawable image to a layer_list with a sized shape and save it as a drawable then use it back:

**your_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image">
        <shape
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

So, just save it to your drawable folder and add it as a thumb (don't forget to change the width and height I put to something fits according to your needs):

```
 android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="R.drawable.your_shape.xml"
```

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve? the before image or the after image? and what is the missing part that you want to achieve

Comment: I want the picture is not stretched

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat your update is not working for me (recyclerview and androidX)

Comment: @JavierSegoviaCordoba what is the result you are getting ?