# ScrollView's scroll is not working inside bottomsheet?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview

I've placed an edit text inside a `NestedScrollView` so that the edit text can be expanded .But the problem is this `NestedScrollView` is placed inside a `BottomSheet` that's why the scrollview is not scrolled.
I wonder how to make the `NestedScrollView` scroll?

My Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relBot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical">
<View
    android:id="@+id/hBot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/headingBot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Comments"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/back_of_bot"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:tint="#fff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left_black_48dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:id="@+id/botRView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:layout_below="@+id/hBot"
 android:layout_above="@+id/linLayCommi"/>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linLayCommi"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 app:cardBackgroundColor="#efeeee"
 android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:hint="Write a Comment..."
    app:backgroundTint="#efeeee"/>
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="end"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#001919">

     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="30dp"
         android:layout_height="25dp"
         android:tint="#fff"
         app:srcCompat="@drawable/emoji_1f58b" />
 </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research I finally solved my issue by placing the scrollview inside a trasperent linear layout as we can't set maxHeight of any view in xml and now it's scrolling .
Ref :https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811461/8953835

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- elements-->
        <!-- elements-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```